# @Autowired an object from external Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to autowire an object from an external JAR that I use it in my application:

```
@Autowired
PythonInterpreter interp;
```

I get this Exception :

> Field interp in com.package.services.ServicesImpl required a bean of type 'org.python.util.PythonInterpreter' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.python.util.PythonInterpreter' in your configuration.

I know that `@ComponentScan` will only work if the class is annotated with `@Component`.

Comment: Write a public method that returns an instance of PythonInterpreter and annotate that method with @Bean.

Comment: *Consider defining a bean of type 'org.python.util.PythonInterpreter' in your configuration.*: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: Thank you @kswaughs , Its work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is: you have to tell Spring **how** to create an instance of that class.

See their example in their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

So, as the first comment correctly tells you: you need to define a method that **somehow** creates that object. Then you annotate that method as @Bean, and make sure that Spring finds it as @Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring** handles dependency injection through the `@Autowired` annotation.When a spring application is initially started it scan packages to discover beans. So all, classes that are annotated or meta-annotated with `@Component` will get picked up during component scan.

- The beans discovered during component scan will then be added to the
  **Spring application context**.
- We can use these beans from the spring application context using the **`@Autowired`** annotation

In your case,you are auto wiring the bean but spring cannot find a bean of type `PythonInterpreter.class` in it's context.That is why it is throwing that error.

The solution to your issue is to register the bean in Spring's application context in a configuration class.We usually register beans by annotation a class with the `@Configuration` (so that spring picks it up for component scan) annotation and the `@Bean` annotation as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

or using xml based configuration as :

```
<beans>
    <bean id="myService" class="com.acme.services.MyServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```